# MIME type mismatch without "charset=utf-8" in <script> tag, error with "charset=utf-8" in <script> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I've deployed an app to heroku. My Javascript code is in a file called main.js. In my index.html file, I point to it like this:

`<script type='text/javascript' src='js/main.js'></script>`

This causes the following error: "The resource from “https://myfreshair.herokuapp.com/js/main.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)."

If I change the tag to read:

`<script type='text/javascript;charset=utf-8' src='js/main.js'></script>`

...I don't get that error. Instead, my code results on an error on its first line. It works fine locally.

Comment: This is likely caused by a 404 on your `.js` file. Most obvious suspicion is that static resources are not being served properly from heroku.

Comment: Yeah, when I try to visit the .js file's location, my browser says `Cannot GET /js/main.js`. The console says `Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at eval (“default-src”).` How can I fix this?

Comment: have you configured static files in your  `config.ru` config?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3#static-assets

Comment: I hosted the Javascript file with Amazon AWS. I'm getting an "access denied" error when I try to visit its public URL. I don't have a `config.ru` file and I've never dealt with one before. My understanding is that they are for Ruby applications, and this is a node application. Please excuse me if I'm wrong; I'm open to anything that will solve my problem.

Comment: no, you are correct about Ruby -0 that was my bad. Heroku is fun isn't it! you have to set permissions on those folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by pointing express to my static files with the following line of code:

```
app.use(express.static('app'));
```

Previously, this line read something like:

```
app.use(express.static('js'));
```